# child element doesn't fill button up

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

I want the inner element (slot in this case) to fill the button up. It works in chrome but doesn't in FireFox. I think there might be use user-agent styles in FireFox. I can't specify how wide the button is because I don't know it's size (not fixed).

jsbin link to play around:

http://jsbin.com/pucapoxizi/1/edit?html,css,output

What I've got so far:

HTML:

```
<button>
  <slot>abc</slot>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
}

slot {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

Screenshots

FireFox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Comment: I don't see an issue. Can you add some image to describe your issue ?

Comment: @Pugazh added screenshots

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0` to `button`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the extra padding for firefox button:

```css
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write css on top of a css reset stylesheet,for example a button reset css

```
button {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    color: inherit;
    /* cursor: default; */
    font: inherit;
    line-height: normal;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* for input */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* for button */
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```